# ko.computed refresh based on another observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I have 2 viewmodels, 1 have an observable and the second have a ko.computed that refer to the other model.
I need to refresh my computed value when the first viewmodel observable is updated.

```
var viewModel1 = {
  value: ko.observable(1)
}
var viewModel2 = {
  result: ko.computed(function() {
    if (viewModel1.value() > 2) {
      return "xxx";
    }
    return "yyy";
  });
}
```

how can I subscribe with "result" to "value" in the other model?

Comment: If your computed has a observable within it, the computed will automatically update itself when an observable within it is updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't knew that and I could fix it because of this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it because adding a call to the observable in the first line (the call was inside a complex code and inside switch/case)

```
var viewModel2 = {
  result: ko.computed(function() {
    ko.viewModel1();
    ...
    if (viewModel1.value() > 2) {
      return "xxx";
    }
    return "yyy";
  });
}
```